# Small Caps Font Property?

Tags: .net, fonts

I'm looking for a way to create a .NET Font object that formats the text like in Word when you check the "Small Caps" check box.  I'm not seeing a Format Style on the Font object to do it, and I was wondering if
A. There is something that I'm missing or 
B. There is a third party library out there (preferably free) that will do it instead.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using WPF have a look at [Typography.Capitals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.capitals.aspx). Also look at this question for some of the pitfalls: [WFP/XAML: Typography.Capitals seems to have no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636454/wfp-xaml-typography-capitals-seems-to-have-no-effect).

I'm not sure if it's going to be an appropriate solution for you, but you might be lucky.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a property. However, you can fake small caps by using normal caps at a smaller font.

Comment: This will look ugly as the thickness of those smaller caps will differ from the first capital letter.