# How to convert lower case to upper case in WPF by XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, lowercase

I tried to convert upper case to lower case by XAML in WPF like below:

```
<TextBox Height="86" CharacterCasing="Upper"/>
```

I want to achieve the same scenario with `TextBlock`, `Label` and `Button`.

How can I do it?

Comment: This is not directly available for a number of controls, You will have create your custom converter and use it.

Comment: ryadavilli, I don't know to create custom converter.Please give me your stuff.

Comment: Why does the question not match its title? lower case ↔ upper case?

Answer (score 9):

You should use a value converter:

```
public class ToUpperValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? string.Empty : str.ToUpper();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: would be nice to add how to use it in xaml, especially when binding resources as text. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1762678/2901207

Answer (score 3):

One way is to do this is to use `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` and handle `TextChanged` event.

XAML

```
<TextBlock Name="TB" Text="{Binding Path=YourProperty, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
               TargetUpdated="TB_TargetUpdated" />
```

Code behind

```
private void TB_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
   TB.Text = TB.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: You could do that but its quite case-specific - you would need to do that for every control.  Much better to use _value converters_ as **David Button** mentions on this page.  Not only are they re-usable but it is the WPF-way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at that: [How to make all text upper case / capital?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762485/wpf-xaml-how-to-make-all-text-upper-case-capital).

More generally, each time you want to transform a value to go into a control, think of a converter and write it yourself (or use it if it already exists).

You can find additional documentation on converters here: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html.