# How to implement a converter in WP8 using XAML and C# for capitalize the first letter of a word in a TexBlock?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textblock, capitalize

I have a data template with a TexBlock in XAML. This TexBlock shows a word in a word list. Every word I want to put the first letter capitalized, because all words are in lowercase.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

In c# implement the converter

```
namespace Converter.ViewModels
```

{

```
    public class ToCapitalizeConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return char.ToUpper(value.ToString()[0]) + value.ToString().Substring(1);
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return (value as string).ToLower();
            }
        }
}
```

In App.xaml

...
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Converter.ViewModels"

```
   <Application.Resources>
          <vm:ToCapitalizeConverter x:Key="ToCapitalizeConverter"/>    
    </Application>
```

In MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding name, Converter={StaticResource ToCapitalizeConverter}}" />                 
                </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
     </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF/XAML: how to make all text upper case / capital?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762485/wpf-xaml-how-to-make-all-text-upper-case-capital)

Comment: I'll change the question because I did not explain the question clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a converter as follows:

```
<TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding name, Converter ={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
```

Specific information on how to implement a converter can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can essentially perform any operation you like on the text. I actually like [Humanizer](http://humanizr.net/#transform-string) to do these type of text conversions.